# When using stacked widget, widget disappears uppon duplication

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I have a scrollArea on the fist page of a stackedWidget. I want to pass that exact scrollArea to the second page on the stackedWidget. Problem is, whenever I add the widget to the second screen, the scrollArea on the first page disappears.

Example code:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

import time

class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(760, 645)
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(Dialog)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.stackedWidget = QtWidgets.QStackedWidget(Dialog)
        self.stackedWidget.setObjectName("stackedWidget")
        self.page = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.page.setObjectName("page")
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.page)
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")


        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.page)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.is_clicked_continue)
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton)



        self.scrollArea = QtWidgets.QScrollArea(self.page)
        self.scrollArea.setStyleSheet("background:rgb(255, 0, 4)")
        self.scrollArea.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.scrollArea.setObjectName("scrollArea")
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 637, 605))
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setObjectName("scrollAreaWidgetContents")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")

        self.scrollArea.setWidget(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.scrollArea)
        self.stackedWidget.addWidget(self.page)


        self.page_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.page_2.setObjectName("page_2")
        self.horizontalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.page_2)

        self.horizontalLayout_2.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_2")


        self.stackedWidget.addWidget(self.page_2)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.stackedWidget, 0, 0, 1, 1)

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        self.stackedWidget.setCurrentIndex(0)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Dialog", "PushButton"))

    def is_clicked_continue(self):
        self.stackedWidget.setCurrentIndex(1)

        self.scrollArea_Previsualizar = self.scrollArea
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.scrollArea_Previsualizar)
        time.sleep(4)
        self.stackedWidget.setCurrentIndex(0)




if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
    ui = Ui_Dialog()
    ui.setupUi(Dialog)
    Dialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

So I have two questions:

1. How do I keep it from disappearing?
2. How can I just completely reset the first page?

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Hope that helps!

Comment: I don't understand. If you put the scroll area in the second page, it is *obviously* removed from the first. You can't have the same widget to be shown twice on different places. That said, you should **never** use a blocking function like `time.sleep` within the main Qt thread.